# android: Is there a way to change/add a property in build.xml via the android tool?

Tags: android, build.xml

I am attempting to add automated build scripts into our android app development process. I am looking at adding in release "signing" and I have read a few articles that mention that the keystore information can be placed in the ant.properties file.

http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html

This is all fine and dandy, but I would like to pull that file "up" a level in our folder structure, such that it is not included in the same folder as my build.xml file. I can change it manually in the build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="MyApp" default="help">
   <property file="..\automated\ant.properties" />
   ...
</project>
```

But since the build file may be regenerated at times, I would like a way to do this from the command line via the android tool (ie. android update project ).

Is there a way to do this?

Thank you muchly!

Comment: Have you considered using the new Gradle based build system instead?

Comment: @Lesleh I have not, but I will give it a read. I looked briefly into Maven, but decided to use a custom python build script (and ant) since many of our other software projects are using that method. Thank you for the heads up.